# Cannot start X servers on different display tabs

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, lightdm

I'm very new to customizing my Desktop with Ubuntu, but I'm trying to get some video games to work.

I'm using 16.04 with Nvidia and after a lot of headaches with frame rates and not being able to fullscreen programs without them crashing, I took a risk and uninstalled the Unity DM and switched to LightDM. This worked, surprisingly, and I can fullscreen games, but I can't *unfullscreen* them. They will stay on top of all programs all the time.

Other topics about this suggest opening a second DM on Ctrl+Alt+8 and then switching between the tabs, but I get this trying to start a second X instance.

I've tried looking up the error and all I can find is stuff about wireless headsets being detected as a mouse but I don't have a wireless headset and even after unplugging all peripherals and just using my laptop touchpad I get the same error.

```
# X :2 

X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux laserbeam 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 18 May 2016  01:07:07AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.2.log", Time: Wed Aug 24 08:46:16 2016
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) BUG: triggered 'if (axnum >= dev->valuator->numAxes)'
(EE) BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:2100 in InitValuatorAxisStruct()
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x556be5cd35ce]
(EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitValuatorAxisStruct+0x67) [0x556be5c641e7]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7fc57eee3000+0x5378) [0x7fc57eee8378]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7fc57eee3000+0x586f) [0x7fc57eee886f]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7fc57eee3000+0x6d63) [0x7fc57eee9d63]
(EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (ActivateDevice+0x4a) [0x556be5b69aaa]
(EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x556be5b21000+0xa27c9) [0x556be5bc37c9]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x556be5b21000+0xb4d2b) [0x556be5bd5d2b]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x556be5b21000+0xb5313) [0x556be5bd6313]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (config_init+0x9) [0x556be5bd4b59]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitInput+0xbb) [0x556be5bb7ccb]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x556be5b21000+0x57bf1) [0x556be5b78bf1]
(EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fc586ab9830]
(EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x29) [0x556be5b62f59]
(EE) 
^[[18~Looking for python... 2.7.12 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
selected
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/wrapper.py", line 149, in <module>
    app = PlayOnLinuxApp(redirect=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8628, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
SystemError: wxEntryStart failed, unable to initialize wxWidgets!  (Is DISPLAY set properly?)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```